# What is the difference between find and findmatchingcontrols

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Recently I started trying to handcode Coded-UI tests and run into an issue with the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.find.aspx) method.

The code I was using:

```vb
    Dim usernameControl As New UITestControl
    usernameControl.TechnologyName = "MSAA"
    usernameControl.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName, "user")
    usernameControl.Find()
    Dim usernameEdit As New WinEdit(usernameControl)
    usernameEdit.text = "myusername"

    Dim passwordControl As New UITestControl()
    passwordControl.TechnologyName = "MSAA"
    passwordControl.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName, "password")
    passwordControl.Find()
    Dim passwordEdit As New WinEdit(passwordControl)
    passwordEdit.text = "mypassword"
```

For some reason the passwordEdit.text function sets the text of the usernameEdit field. After I replaced the [.Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.find.aspx) with [.FindMatchingControls()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.findmatchingcontrols.aspx) it started working.

```
    usernameControl.Find() VS usernameControl.FindMatchingControls()
```

The [documentation of these functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.findmatchingcontrols.aspx) is extremely light, so light I cannot understand the difference.

The leads to the following questions:

- What is the difference between these two functions?
- Could you give an example when to use which?
- Is there better documentation of the Coded-UI methods?

Comment: The following question is similar, the answers contains some more info about these functions, but I still do not understand why the one works and the other not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962011/cant-determine-if-a-certain-uitestcontrol-exists-in-my-web-app

Comment: Please show the code that works and that uses `FindMatchingControls`.

Comment: Just replace the 2x .Find() with .FindMatchingControls()

Comment: `Find()` only succeeds when *exactly* one item matches, it then returns that item. `FindMatchingControls()` returns a possibly empty list of controls. I suggest you add code after the call of `FindMatchingControls()` to display the number of items found, or use the debugger to see what `usernameEdit` and `passwordEdit` contain. I suspect that an empty list is returned so your code is, effectively, saing `Dim xxx As New WinEdit(null)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think my problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't see the code you're trying to test this is going to be a guess:

You're looking for the control named password, since you're not specifying it's a WinEdit it might just find the first control named password. Which, if my guess is correct, could be the text above the password field.

Two options, rename the password control to PasswordInput and search specifically for that.

Second option is to search for a winEdit control instead of a UiTestControl:

```
Dim passwordEdit As New WinEdit()
passwordEdit.TechnologyName = "MSAA"
passwordEdit.SearchProperties.Add(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName, "password")
passwordEdit.Find()
passwordEdit.text = "mypassword"
```

Comment: Thanks, yes giving the elements better unique names will help, but as I am working on writing tests for a legacy applications I want to try and not change the applications code, unless necessary. I have the feeling I do not even need the .Find() function as-long the search returns only one control, but somehow the MSAA tech with ControlName returns random controls. :) Other techs seem to work better.

Comment: Try using .DrawHighlight(); before and after the .Find() to see if the test finds the correct control before adding the text.

Comment: Wow, that .DrawHighlight() extremely handy for debugging!

Comment: Only use it for debugging though, it will give a playback performance penalty for 7 seconds or more!

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your main question difference between `UITestControl.Find` and `UITestControl.FindMatchingControls`

After you apply Search or Filter on a perticular control, if you want your search for that control to be triggered then you use Find whose written type is Void.
Whereas FindMatchingControls also triggers search with return type as collection of `UITestControlCollection` which has all the controls which are matching with given search or filter.

However there is one more control which returns bool that is `TryFind`

Comment: Thanks, this is helpfull. I would except Find to return something, guess I have to use the TryFind.