# Coded UI UITestControl - What's the difference between SearchProperties and FilterProperties

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm just starting out with Coded UI tests. The FilterProperties and SearchProperties in the UITestControl class appear to do the same thing, am I missing something?

The documentation isn't that helpful either:

[UITestControl.FilterProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.filterproperties.aspx)

> Gets the property-value pair collection that is used to disambiguate a control.

[UITestControl.SearchProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.searchproperties.aspx)

> Gets the property-value pair collection that is used to identify a control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't determine if a certain UITestControl exists in my web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962011/cant-determine-if-a-certain-uitestcontrol-exists-in-my-web-app) where an answer explains the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coded UI tests works in such a way that.  It scans through the SUT for Search properties with "AND" conditions, if all those are met, then Coded UI identifies the UITestControl under SUT.  If even with Search Properties, if a UITestControl was not found, then CodedUI starts looking for Filter Properties with "OR" condition.  If any of the filter properties are met, then Coded UI finds the UITestControl under SUT.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I love the SO police making me upvote and mark this as an answer yet again.